# Writing my own ufunc; ufunc not supported for the input types

Tags: python, numpy, python-c-api, numpy-ufunc

I'm trying to write a C function that coverts numpy string array to a float array. How can I receive numpy's array in C as const char *?

```
static void double_logitprod(char **args, npy_intp *dimensions,
                            npy_intp* steps, void* data)
{
    npy_intp i;
    npy_intp n = dimensions[0];
    char *in1 = args[0], *in2 = args[1];
    char *out = args[2];
    npy_intp in1_step = steps[0]; 
    npy_intp out_step = steps[2];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        /*BEGIN main ufunc computation*/
        char *tmp1 = *((char **) in1);
        double tmp2 = *((double *)in2);
        *((double *) out) = to_float(tmp1, tmp2);
        /*END main ufunc computation*/

        in1 += in1_step;
        out += out_step;
    }
}


/*This a pointer to the above function*/
PyUFuncGenericFunction funcs[1] = {&double_logitprod};

/* These are the input and return dtypes of logit.*/

static char types[3] = {NPY_STRING, NPY_DOUBLE,
                        NPY_DOUBLE};
```

How to accept a numpy string array in C? NPY_STRING or NPY_UNICODE gives error.

Numpy string array is like this:

```
x = np.array(['1.0', '2.0', 'N/A'])
```

Comment: `np.genfromtxt` which (as a default) returns `nan` for strings it can't convert to floats, uses a `StringConverter` class object to the do the conversion.  This code is found in `np.lib,_iotools`.  Conversion is applied to list of strings.  Since conversion necessarily uses Python objects (strings, floats), speed gains from 'compiling' will be, at best, modest.